# How to ensure unique IDs when inserting into SQLite database in R shiny?

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I have a shiny app where users should be able to add, edit and delete rows of a `data.frame`, so based on this question https://community.rstudio.com/t/persistent-data-storage-in-apps-with-multiple-users/1308 I chose to use an `SQLite` database to store the data.

I have an id column which should be a unique ascending integer. How can I assure that this is unique, e.g. when two users insert data at the same time? The second part of the question is how to retrieve the latest data in Shiny whenever there is a change in the database?

This is what I currently have, which allows to read, add, delete and edit rows, but does not check that id's are unique:

```
library(tibble)
library(RSQLite)

## Create test data.base
db_user <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2),
  user = c("markus", "alex")
)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "test.sqlite")    
dbWriteTable(con, name = "test", value = db_user, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)  
dbDisconnect(con)

## -------------------

library(shiny)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(DBI)

pool <- dbPool(RSQLite::SQLite(),
  dbname = "test.sqlite")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("read", "Read data"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  hr(),
  textInput("new.user", "New User"),
  numericInput("new.id", "New ID", 1),
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  hr(),
  numericInput("edit.id", "select id to edit", value = 1),
  textInput("edit.user", "Edited User"),
  actionButton("edit", "Edit"),
  hr(),
  numericInput("delete.id", "select id to delete", value = 1),
  actionButton("delete", "Delete")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$read, {
    values$data <- pool %>%
      tbl("test") %>%
      collect()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(values$data)
    values$data
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    #db_insert_into(pool, "test", data.frame(id = input$new.id, user = input$new.user))
    dbWriteTable(pool, "test", data.frame(id = input$new.id, user = input$new.user),
      append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$edit, {
    col <- "id"
    entryValues <- data.frame(user = input$edit.user, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    print(entryValues)
    sql <- paste0("UPDATE ?table SET ",
      paste0(names(entryValues), " = ?", names(entryValues), collapse = ", "),
      " WHERE ", col, " = ?idVal;")
    print(sql)
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, .dots = c(
      list(table = "test"),
      as_list(entryValues),
      list(idVal = as.character(input$edit.id))
    ))
    print(query)
    dbExecute(pool, query)
  })

  observeEvent(input$delete, {
    print(input$delete.id)
    col <- "id"
    sql <- paste0("DELETE FROM ?table WHERE ", col, " IN (",
      paste0(input$delete.id, collapse = ", "), ");")
    print(sql)
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, table = "test")
    dbExecute(pool, query)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an id column which should be a unique ascending integer. How can I assure that this is unique, e.g. when two users insert data at the same time?

If the column is defined with as `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` where ?? is the column name. Then `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` makes it an alias for the **rowid** (if you have **not** coded `WITHOUT ROWID`).

**rowid** will always be unique and generally ascending.

`AUTOINCREMENT` enforces ascending but not necessarily ascending by 1. However, it does so at some additional cost.

There is also the limitation that the highest id can be 9223372036854775807. If this is reached then an SQLITE_FULL exception will be encountered.

You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)